# cakephp cannot bake and system propeerties

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new to the CakePHP and first starting to bake so I face this problem when following a tutorial and do the following.

Am having issues baking my cake models. I guess my path (in the "*system properties > advanced settings*") is the issue. The error in command prompt is

> cake is not recognized an internal or external command.....

My path looks like this:

```
"%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32;C\xampp\php;"
```

I just re-installed my OS (windows 7), and i mistakenly deleted some url in my path, when i first opened it, maybe thats what is givin the problem...

Comment: You are most likely simply not targeting the console directory properly, hard to tell without know the exact command you are trying to run. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html

Comment: am trying to bake my model, controller and view files... but its not running.. Have added php to the path and my cake document... but still gettin error dat cake is not recognized

Comment: please show us how are you calling the bake command

Comment: in My Command Prompt,   with C:\Users\ayo 'lana> cake     The error am gettin after I execute this command is  'cake is not recognized as an external or internal, operable or batch file'